# reading data from xml feed using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Im using simplexml to bring in a data feed, and now i want to put that into working varables to use in my php doc.

Following the php.net guides on simplexml ive arrived at

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('f1_feed.xml');

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    echo $xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market[0]->name;
?>
```

but i keep getting a blank page, have i completely missed to point of how to parse the xml and put it into a working var ?

(feed is local for development)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need both `new SimpleXMLElement`  and `simplexml_load_file`:

- [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement
- [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) Returns a SimpleXMLElement object

try:

```
  if (file_exists('f1_feed.xml')) {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file('f1_feed.xml');    
      print_r($xml);
  } else {
      exit('Failed to open f1_feed.xml.');
  }
```

or:

```
if (file_exists('f1_feed.xml')) {
     $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('f1_feed.xml'));
     echo $xml->response->williamhill->class->type->market[0]->name;
} else {
     exit('Failed to open f1_feed.xml.');
}
```

if it still doesn't work, add

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

for better error reporting